# jquery resize nested divs

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am just starting working with jquery and have encountered the following problem

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content" contenteditable="true">
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

If I'm using `$(...).resizable()` how can I make both of them resize at the same time? which `overflow` value would work?

also, would making the "container" draggable affect anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#container, #content").resizable({
        alsoResize: "#content, #container"
    });
    $('#container').draggable();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KmCGg/18/)**

Answer (score 2):

sure, it's possible.  try this demo:

[the jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/KmCGg/)

make sure both divs are .resizable().  make sure the outer resize div is dependent on the resize event of the inner div.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer
jQuery provides the following:

```
$("#container").resizable({alsoResize:"#content"});
```

and that seems to do the job really well :)